# Android Grouped Notification (from OneSignal) crashes app when trying to open

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

Clicking on single notifications from OneSignal opens my app without issues, but if I have a grouped notification, it attempts to open the app and then closes it without much error. The only thing I can really see of relevance in my output logs is there are multiple "Activity_launch_request", one for each notification in the group, as soon as I click the grouped notification. (My device is a Xiaomi Mi Max, that tag may just be specific to this device)

Relevant notification click handling code:

```
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            bug.out("notificationOpened");
            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

            Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidLauncher.this, AndroidLauncher.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AndroidLauncher.this, 0, intent, 0);
            try {
                contentIntent.send();
            } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Note that even though "Activity_launch_request" gets fired "group_count" times, "notificationOpened" only gets printed once, so it's safe to say my launch intent only gets fired once.

My activity launchMode is "singleTop".

Can someone please help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a payload and AndroidManifest issue, our website url was in the payload and my AndroidManifest had an intent-filter to launch the app from our url.